# load assembly based only on its name

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I have a .net Type that is serialized to a string str with the `AssemblyQualifiedName` method.
Later I want to access this Type by using `Type.GetType(str);`

Now the issue is that the assembly version has changed in the months between serialization and deserialization of the type. I then created a custom assembly resolver to remove the version:

```
Type.GetType(str,
                assemblyName =>
                {
                    assemblyName.Version = null;
                    return System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
                },
                null // type resolver : default
                );
```

This works but I have several questions about this:

- is it normal that the public token key is kept the same in between versions in my case? what makes them change? Is it possible to remove as well the identification of the public token key? (like I did with the version)
- is it the correct way to do this? Ideally I would just like to load the given type in the given assembly, but I feel like I'm doing something incorrect

thanks